# How to persist MongoDB Doctrine with update multiple

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine

I'm getting some problems working with data that I just updated in mongodb. I expect to work with the new data, but it looks like there is some kind of cache in the process that keep working with the old one.

This is how I update the documents:

```
$this->dm->createQueryBuilder(Event::class)
            ->update()
            ->multiple(true)
            ->field('account')->equals($account->getId())
            ->field('tracker')->in($trackers)
            ->field('first')->set(false)
            ->field('groupId')->set($groupId)
            ->getQuery()->execute();

        $this->flush();
```

If I check the db directly, I can see the updates there well done. But if I try to access from the same process to this data. (for example, getting the groupId of the document) I still get the old one.

How can I make my script to work with the updated document?

I'm using symfony2, mongodb and php5.6

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, adding this line after the flush():

```
$this->dm->getUnitOfWork()->clear(Event::class);
```

Comment: Also if you'd like to not clear UnitOfWork you can [`refresh` results of queries](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/query-builder-api.html#refreshing-documents) if that's how you're fetching data later

Comment: @malarzm, thanks for your reply. I tried to put refresh() in the createQueryBuilder call, but it didn't work. This is the only way that I get to reload data from db.

Comment: The refresh can be used in later query fetching data that was already managed. Also (just noticed) flushing DM is not needed unless you had more documents to update, update queries work separately :)